# removing jva openjdk 7, ubuntu 15.04

Tags: java, openjdk

Can I safety remove OpenJDK 7 from my system? I've got OpenJDK 8 but I've found this:

> I suppose you are using 12.10 or 13.04. Here default-jre depends on
>   openjdk-7-jre. So you can't remove openjdk-7 without removing also
>   default-jre and break a lot of other dependencies.

Is it the same on Ubuntu 15.04?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove OpenJDK, it will break dependencies, but these dependencies are only related to Java. If you uninstall it, anything that requires Java to run will not work until you install OpenJDK again. Also, there's not big reason to uninstall OpenJDK 7. It still works with everything v8 does, and is more stable.